NextUI Select Component not clickable when placed inside a Dialog element
I am trying to create a Form within a Modal in Next.js I have already created the Dialog component, and am working on the specific format of the Modal for this page. I copy and pasted the Select component code directly from NextUi, and when I first added it to my project, the select items showed up, but the format was wonky (unfortunately I am not currently able to recreate this issue). However now, they are just not showing up at all, and the Select component is seemingly not clickable. Can anyone tell if there is something I am missing?
const associates = getCallForwardAssociates();
        
<Dialog ref={dialogRef} title='Reassign Caller' onClose={onClose}>
            <Form action='/dashboard/home'>
                <Select
                    label="Select Caller"
                    placeholder=""
                    className="max-w-xs"
                >
                    {associates.map((associate) => (
                        <SelectItem key={associate.id} textValue={`${associate.firstName} ${associate.lastName}`}>
                            {associate.firstName} {associate.lastName}
                        </SelectItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
            </Form>
        </Dialog>


Note: the Dialog component itself is rendering just fine, and the label/placeholder for the select component is visible. The Associates array is coming from an api that I have tested to ensure the getCallForwardAssociates function accurately produces the desired array of information.

